# Disable Window Switching in Cairo-Dock

Tags: cairo-dock

I'm freshly installed Cairo-Dock in Ubuntu 14.04.when i use key combination **Alt+Tab** Cairo-Dock also shows up its own window switcher overlapping with Unity window Switcher.

How can i Disable these window-switcher in Cairo-Dock ?

Comment: **off-topic: went away all by its own!**  :P

Answer (score 0):

When I do a Post here Reboot was not performed. After doing a reboot,the problem was solved.